# Can you watch movies from an external USB flash drive on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, flash-memory

I intend to use a USB drive with Lightening port support (for use on iOS device), such as this:

- https://www.amazon.ca/SanDisk-iXpand-Flash-Drive-iPhone/dp/B01CIEBS74

or this:

- https://www.amazon.ca/HooToo-certificated-Connector-compatible-Expansion/dp/B01I1B5KFY/

If I put movies on either one, and the plugged it into an iPhone, would it be able to play those movies? If so is it through the Files app or something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pick an external store device that comes with an app to play content on the device.

> Stream videos to up to 3 devices—at the same time
>
> SanDisk Connect Wireless Stick is a great entertainer, too. You can
>   stream music or videos1 to three smartphones, tablets or computers as
>   long as they’re somewhere in the vicinity—the back seat, the next tent
>   or the other end of the conference table.

https://www.sandisk.com/home/mobile-device-storage/connect-wireless-stick